# ESP8266 wake from deep sleep

Tags: esp8266, low-power, gpio

I am currently building a simple device that runs on ESP8266, with just 2 buttons - power and deep sleep (which will stream WiFi access point on disabled state)

At this point, whenever I want to disable the deep sleep button (from enabled state), **I need to power off the device first, then power it on** - and this additional unnecessary steps is not something i wanted

I need to have it disabled only by switching off the deep sleep button. If restarting required, at least it could restart automatically upon switching the button off

Desperately looking for workaround. No luck with google searches.
Any ideas?

Comment: What does the manual say about deep sleep? What things can wake it up from deep sleep? There should be a list, or if not, you can still find them in a few minutes by Ctrl-F-ing for words like "sleep" and "wake"

Comment: I found this tutorial very handy when configuring sleep mode.  Maybe it has your answer? https://www.mischianti.org/2019/11/21/wemos-d1-mini-esp8266-the-three-type-of-sleep-mode-to-manage-energy-savings-part-4/

Comment: as I understand the question, OP has a problem with own code (states), not with the deep sleep function of the esp8266